# Java - How to copy each element of array to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Why this didn't work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Vector 
{
    ArrayList<Long> vector;
    public Vector(long ...vector)
    {
        for (long value : vector)
            this.vector.add(new Long(value));
    }
}
```

when I make a new objet like `Vector a = new Vector(4,7,8);` it says

`java.lang.NullPointerException`

I've tried `Arrays.asList(array);` and

```
for (int i=0;i<vector.lenght;i++)
    this.vector.add(vector[i])
```

and same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, in that the code to copy to an arraylist is properly written. However, the fact that the error is a `NullPointerException` clues us into knowing that something is null where it shouldn't be. In this case, `vector` itself is null, since it never got assigned a value. You can either declare `vector` and assign it using `ArrayList<Long> vector = new ArrayList<>();`, *or* assign `vector = new ArrayList<>();` in the constructor.

Note: The `<>` diamond shorthand is a shorthand for generic types available in Java 7 and higher. If targeting Java 6, use `new ArrayList<Long>();` on the right-hand-side.